# How can I Identify corresponding response of request out of 10 users in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have two HTTP requests in a thread: GetOpt and verifyOtp. 
**User**:10,
**ramp-up**(in sec):1 (As I want all 10 users to request for otp simultaneously),
**loop**:1.
 How can I map particular request for its response?

Comment: you can add unique id,no?

Comment: where should I add unique Id?

Comment: in request add irrelevant parameter as &myuniqueid=${__Random(0,10)}

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes samplers upside-down, so something like:

1. Thread x starts
2. Thread x executes `GetOpt`
3. Thread x executes `verifyOtp`
4. Thread x shuts down

So each JMeter thread will first execute `GetOpt` followed by `verifyOtp`. You can get individual threads response times looking into .jtl results file

[image: JMeter .jtl results file thread name]

if you look into `threadName` column you will see something like

```
Thread Group 1-1
Thread Group 1-2
Thread Group 1-3
etc.
```

where the second number is the number of thread. You can also get it using [threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

Also 1 second ramp-up time doesn't guarantee that all requests will be simultaneous, better option is using [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra parameter with unique ID

```
&myuniqueid=${UUID()}
```

Comment: How should I use  this randomly generated Id in response to identify it for particular request?

Answer (score 0):

I started getting the desired response by just deselecting **Run thread groups consecutively** in Test Plan